# How would i set the button to toggle viewability of the javascript array?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make it to where the button in the paragraph is used to toggle the viewability of the javascript array on/off. I'm not quite sure how to do it though.

Here's my html:

```
<body>
    <div class="flexbox-container">
            <h1 class="underline-small">
                Heading One
            </h1>
        </div>
        <h3 class="paragraph">Remove the duplicates in 2 Javascript arrays (found in readme), add the results to an array and output the list of distinct names in an unordered list below this paragraph when <button type="button" onclick="unshow()" id="btnID" class="javabutton">this link</button> is clicked. If the operation has been completed already, notify the user that this has already been done.</h2>
            <script>
                function unshow() {
                    document.getElementById('image')
                            .style.display = "none";
                }
            </script>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let array1 = ["Matt Johnson", "Matt Johnson", "Bart Paden", "Ryan Doss", "Jared Malcolm"]
        array2 = ["Matt Johnson", "Bart Paden", "Ryan Doss", "Jared Malcolm", "Jordan Heigle", "Tyler Viles"]

        let set = new Set([...array1, ...array2]);

        let newArray = [...set];

        for(i=0;i<newArray.length;i++) {
            document.write(newArray[i] + "<br/>");
        }
    </script>
       
          </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and here's my CSS for styling:

```
.paragraph {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: -30px 75px 0px 75px;
}

.javabutton {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #DEBF79;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #222222;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have random HTML content outside of your `<body>` tag? And what looks like an orphaned `</div>` immediately before the `</body>`...

Comment: My bad, I'm pretty new to this thank you for pointing it out though I'll have it edited.